# Use values of functions in 3rd task

Tags: python, airflow

I've been looking around and can't find a solution for my issue. I have a DAG that is mainly checking that the backups are correct, so 1 task connects to a MySql DB and the 2nd one connects to a Postgres. Once I get those counts I want to send those results to another task that checks whether or not they match:

```py
def mysql_count_validator(**kwargs):
    db_hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id='MySQL_DB')

    # Query to grab desired results:
    df_mysql = db_hook.get_pandas_df('''
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM `schema`.`table`;
        ''')
    
    # Save query results in a variable:
    return df_mysql

def postgres_count_validator(**kwargs):
    db_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='Postgres_DB')

    # Query to grab desired results:
    df_postgress = db_hook.get_pandas_df('''
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM `schema`.`table`;
        ''')

    # Save query results in a variable:
    return df_postgres

def validator(**kwargs):    
        if df_mysql == df_postgres:
            print('Matched')
        else:
            print('Not Matched!')


mysql_count_validator = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'mysql_count_validator',
    python_callable = mysql_count_validator
)

postgres_count_validator = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'postgres_count_validator',
    python_callable = postgres_count_validator
)

validator = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'validator',
    python_callable = validator,
    op_kwarg = {df_mysql, df_postgres}
)

[mysql_count_validator, postgres_count_validator] >> validator
```

I tried passing it to the Xcom since it's only one line per task, so the data is not that big; but still not luck. Is it the way I'm saving the query results that is causing the issue or am I missing anything else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly have you tried for XCOM and what exactly didn't work? The DAG part that you've provided won't even load because df_mysql and df_postgres are undefined in the global scope.

Comment: True, but by returning the variable I'm automatically pushing them to the XCOM. This is what confirmed it for me:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_xcom.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some trial and error I was able to pass the variable into the 3rd task.

My issue was not calling the pull in the third function:

```
def validator(**kwargs):
        df_mysql = kwargs['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='mysql_count_validator')
        df_postgress = kwargs['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='postgres_count_validator')

        if df_mysql == df_postgress:
            print('Matched')
        else:
            print(f'Not Matched!\nMySQL: {df_mysql}\nPostgres: {df_postgress}')

validator = PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'validator',
        python_callable = validator,
        provide_context = True
    )
```